# What was the role of U.S. involvement in World War II?

Tags: united-states, world-war-two

I recently read the book *1945* by Newt Gingrich and Harry Turtledove, where the premise is that Hitler got injured, and his advisers chose to wait to attack Russia until winning on the western front, meanwhile the US fought and defeated Japan without ever getting involved in the war in Europe (due to various political issues that are mentioned in the book). Because of this, the Nazis won the war, and now control almost all of Europe, excepting Britain. 
What I'm asking is are there any indicators of what would've happened without US involvement (which was far from guaranteed in the first place)?

What were the actual U.S. contributions to the Allies in World War II, and how did they compare with the hypothesized U.S. contributions in the 1945 book that featured a the Nazis getting a "Cold War" (rather than total domination) against the United States. 
Note that I'm not asking for speculation, rather for historical facts of any kind that might shed light on the subject.

Comment: You might find that this gets closed as off topic as it's about alternate history. It seems to me you might get the results you are looking for by looking at/asking about the reasons stated for wanting the US to join; finding out about what was needed might just tell you what might have happened otherwise.

Comment: The problem is that to an extent I am asking about alternate history. I'm not trying to find out the causes for what happened, nor asking what the alternate history would've looked like, rather looking for actual facts that could tell us what else would've happened.

Comment: ...which cannot really be answered except by rank speculation on our users' part. [Alternate history](http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/questions/572/are-alternative-history-questions-allowed) questions almost always get closed here. I could see where a question asking about the soundness of particular bits of reasoning in that book *might* stay open, but even that would probably be a close call.

Comment: Hypothetical questions are off topic.

Comment: Quoting Newt Gingrich in the context of historical scholarship is like inviting Will Farrell to give a speech at the Institute for Advanced Study at Princeton.

Comment: There's something i want to get off my chest: i don't think the invasion of Russia was the determining factor. It still was a very stupid and stubborn decision but i think the Germans could have succeeded in Russia if it weren't for the Italians. Involuntarily, the Italians saved the day, because they were so incompetent in the Balkans and Greece, that they failed to handle their mare nostrum ambitions themselves and Germany had to withdraw a great deal of force from the eastern front to aid its allies.

Comment: I don't see this question as being opinion-based (as edited). It asks people to compare the actual U.S, contribution to the war, as opposed to the fictitious contribution, and explain why the hypothetical results were different from the actual.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for a comparison to a non-historical counterfactual.

Comment: @Matthaeus - I think you vastly over-estimate the troop commitments the Germans made in the Adriatic and North Africa. The German units in the North Africa Corps were only a handful of *divisions*. To put this into perspective, in the 4 months of the Battle of Moscow, the Germans took more casualties than the total number of soldiers that *had ever served* in North Africa.

Comment: @Comintern : forgive me if i cite Wikipedia (i know it's not popular here) but there were about 600000 German soldiers deployed in the Balkans, and about the same amount of Italian soldiers. That is a considerable force of 1,2 million soldiers combined, which is about a third of the axis soldiers who fought on the eastern front, leaving out north Africa. I think increasing the number of troops and material by over 30% is a relevant amount. The plan was to expediently deal with Yugoslavia and Greece, and then join the eastern front.

Comment: @Comintern: also, in order to remain on-topic, i might add that the number of troops provided by the US pre 1944 was vastly inferior to commonwealth (british) troops, and even after 1944 american troops just barely outnumbered commonwealth and french troops in france, and were still outnumbered by other allied forces elsewhere in Europe. So while the american intervention played a major strategical and numerical (maybe even psychological) role, the extent (in terms of numbers) of american aid might sometimes be overestimated.

Comment: @Comintern : even in the pacific commonwealth and chinese troops are often disregarded and left out of the equation: the british had over a million soldiers fighting before the americans landed even a division and well into 1943 the australian army alone deployed more ground forces than the anericans.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The U.S. contributions to World War II fell under three broad categories:

1. Lend Lease Aid to key Allies such as Britain, the Soviet Union and China.
2. Fighting Germany's allies, Japan and Italy
3. Introduction of U.S. air and ground forces into western Europe.

In the 1945 book, the main U.S. contribution to the war was the defeat of Japan (with China becoming a "third world" power aligned neither with the United States nor Nazi Germany). That was basically a minimum condition for American survival.

The hypothesis from my unpublished World War II book "Axis Overstretch" is that the Axis win if they ever obtain control of 50% or more of the world's industrial capacity. According to Paul Kennedy's "Imperial Overstretch," North and South America had just under 45% of the world's industrial capacity in the 1940s. Add Australia, Japan and the latter's holdings in the ASEAN nations of Southeast Asia, and you get just over 50% for the U.S.-led bloc.

The 1945 book presupposed the failure of American Lend Lease aid and the resulting inability of America to protect Britain and the Soviet Union. In the "real" war, American Lend Lease aid approximated the total Axis output, thereby giving America's allies a meaningful preponderance of material against the Axis, which was enough for them to survive.

The introduction of American military forces in western Europe was the "icing on the cake," that sealed the fate of Nazi Germany. Even without this, the more pressing need was to ensure the survival of  Britain and the Soviet Union, and the defeat of Japan. Britain and the Soviet Union had a bare preponderance of strength against Nazi Germany alone (the danger of U.S. non-intervention was that Japan would tip the balance in Germany's favor). Throw in U.S. power and the "bare preponderance" of Allied power in Europe becomes overwhelming.

Comment: In the real war, the Soviets also massively outproduced the Axis block on their own, ignoring Lend Lease.

Comment: @Oldcat: The Soviet Union outproduced Germamy 2 to 1 in weaponry with 2/3 the industrial capacity. But one reason was the large amount of Lend Lease RAW materials (aluminum, oil, cotton), rather than weaponry.